# Partial derivative problem

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Using differentials to approximate increments to find the amount of material in a hollow
rectangular box, whose inside measurements are 5ft long, 3ft wide, and 2ft deep, if the
box made of lumber that is 0.5inche thick and the box has no top?

what I understand in this question is $x=5$ , $y=3 $, $z=2$ and the function that must be used to find the volume is this$f(x,y,z)=x*y*z$ and the thickness is $0.5 inches$ so we have to find the volume with respect to that as well

I want the answer with steps and by using partial derivatives and I don't even know where to start and what to do!

use this:- $$df=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}dx+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}dy+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}dz $$

$$0.5in=\frac{1}{24}ft$$

In my textbook, it requires the change of volume (delta V) and the answer is ($\frac{47}{24}$) but I don't know the solution.

Comment: Does the question give the rates of change for the length, width and height? The question would be unsolvable without these pieces of information.

Comment: @tobymak there is no rate of change, it's (Finding Approximate value)

Comment: I don't get your question then. What do you mean by 'approximating increments'? What exactly is 'amount of material' - maybe the surface area of the material? Are the formulas shown your formulas or are they from somewhere else, such as your textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote the thickness by $a$. The volume of the material is equal to
\begin{align} \Delta V = (x+2a)(y+2a)(z+a) -xyz &\approx a\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\big((x+2t)(y+2t)(z+t)\big) = \\
&= a \cdot\Big(2\frac{\partial (xyz)}{\partial x} + 2\frac{\partial (xyz)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial (xyz)}{\partial z}\Big) = \\
&= a(2yz+2xz+xy) = \\
&= \frac{47}{24} \text{ ft}^3\end{align}
The result doesn't quite match the answer you're given (47 vs 27), but I believe this is a typo in your book.

Comment: how can I get $\frac{27}{24}$ with this? please explain

Comment: You get $\frac{47}{24}$, I believe there is a typo in your book.

Comment: thanks got it...